# What datetime NodeJS uses when a new date is created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

Does NodeJS/JavaScript uses the server date?

I have a script in my NodeJS where I format the date before inserting it in the MySQL database.

```
const today = new Date();
const formattedDate = (date) => {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

Then I run whenever I want to insert it: `'${formattedDate(today)}'`

However, I notice it is saving the wrong date. Not today's date. Does NodeJS get the server date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `today` variable is a constant assigned once to today's date when the program is first run (or actually when this file is imported). So if your problem is that you don't get today's date several days after starting the program, this is why. Just call `new Date()` every time you need today's date, or make today into a function.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean, I should use ```${formattedDate(new Date())}``` instead of ```${formattedDate(today)}```?

Comment: That's an easy fix, yes. There's little reason to declare a constant for today's date, as it's only valid temporarily.